# Query WHERE date is more recent than 14 days

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find a way to do a request in MySQL such as this one :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE insert_date < '14 days'
```

From googling, I found two answers :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE insert_date < DateAdd(dd,-14,GetDate())
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE insert_date < DateAdd(day,Datediff(day,0,getdate()),-14)
```

So here are my questions :

1) Are there better ways to do this ?

2) What is the difference between the two things I found ?

Thanks

Comment: What is `DateAdd`? That's not a MySQL function. Do you mean [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Google'd answers are for SQL Server, not MySQL.

All of them are getting dates *older* than 14 days ago, not *more recent*.

So, I think you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE insert_date > date_sub(curdate(), interval 14 day);
```